# how to apend specific json value to a specific span in javascript

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to check some specific items in the bellow objects. Actually this is json encoded format. The data `subject_name`, `mark`, `exam_name` are database fields. The data is taken through an AJAX call to the controller.

HTML

```
<span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua">FA1</span>
<div class="info-box-content">
  <ul class="top3SubAnlysList">
    <li> <span class="info-box-text pull-left" id="fa1_top1"></span>
      <span class="info-box-number pull-right label label-warning"><small>%</small></span></li>

    <li><span class="info-box-text pull-left" id="fa1_top2"></span>
      <span class="info-box-number pull-right label label-danger"><small>%</small></span></li>

    <li><span class="info-box-text pull-left" id="fa1_top3"></span>
      <span class="info-box-number pull-right label label-success"><small>%</small></span></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

JSON

```
"top_3":[  
  {  
     "subject_name":"Eng",
     "mark":"9.65",
     "exam_name":"FA1",
  },
  {  
     "subject_name":"math",
     "mark":"9.38",
     "exam_name":"FA1",
   }
  ]
}
```

AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"<? echo base_url();?>student_analysis/get_fa", 
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {id:id},      
        success:function(result) {

   }
 });
```

Here I want to append `exam_name` `fa1`'s corresponding subject names to each `span` elment. How can it possible?

Comment: You need to use probably `.each` to loop the result object and take the subject name and append to span html either by accessing the id or by looping the ul li.

Answer (score 0):

```
var exeval=top_3[0].exe_name;
$("#spanid").html(exeval);
```

Comment: replace 0 to 1 fro second val